# How do I substitute two same words (of different cases) to another two words whilst retaining their original cases?

Tags: command-line, substitute, letter-case

I am sorry that my English was not good enough to clearly describe the task in the title.

Here is a more descriptive attempt. Let us say I have the following text

```
\gls{tla}{TLA}
```

(As a side note, this is a partial excerpt from a `latex` document. This command is useful for defining acronyms and generating glossary later on.)

The question is the following: Let us say, I have copied  the line immediately below with `yyp`.

```
\gls{tla}{TLA}
\gls{tla}{TLA}
```

I wish to change the second line to the following with a single edit operation.

```
\gls{tla}{TLA}
\gls{tbd}{TBD}
```

i.e. I wish to perform a substitution for the case-sensitive and case-insensitive version in one go. I believe this is possible with some knowledgeable vim-fu, since it involves only a single semantic transformation (and the case conversion can be seen as a side-effect/add-on operation that remain fixed in sequence.)

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I am not opposed to the use of plugins to aid this, but standalone & elegant pure vim-only solutions (with some very-magic regex) will also be highly appreciated.

Comment: I know you said you prefer a non-plugin solution, but this sounds like a prime use-case of https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish

Comment: @Mass, cool. I just tried and that indeed did work! . In the meantime, I have to do about 70 of these glossary terms in my thesis. I am new to vim. Can you suggest a vimscript function that will relieve the burden from manually specifying the word to substitute. I just want to keep the structure ```\gls{something}{SOMETHING}``` and keep moving on with my definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are starting with the following, i.e., after changing all the first arguments using any text editing method (e.g., visual block mode).

```
\gls{tbd}{TLA}
\gls{foo}{TLA}
\gls{bar}{TLA}
```

Now, all we need to do is make the second argument match.  A simple way to do this is:

```
:%s/\\gls{\(\w\+\)}{\zs\w*\ze}/\=toupper(submatch(1))
```

Breaking it down, we look for `\gls{word}{..}` and capture the word into group `\1`.  Targeting only the second argument using `\zs..\ze`, we replace with a transformed version of the `word` (`\=` allows us to use an expression for replacement).